# Tag:technical-issues - not useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen user Ola Ström add the tag [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) to a lot of questions, all of which I, without exception I think, accepted. The tag description lets users know it is important to note down their system specifics, and it seems to me the tag neatly groups a specific kind of question.

I wonder then why it was rejected from this post:

[Minecraft won't launch!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354217/minecraft-wont-launch)

[image: users Ivo Coumans and Joachim accepted, user galacticninja rejected the tag edit]

Comment: It says approved in your screenshot and the question, so it should be fine. You need two votes to either approve or reject a suggested edit and only have one for rejection.

Comment: @dly I understand, but I wonder what galacticninja's reason for rejection is and, by extension, what the general opinion is.

Comment: I know some use it as a filter to either show or hide technical support questions.